# Tengo problemas usando firebase con react

Tags: nodejs, firebase, reactjs

tengo el siguiente código

justo aquí comienza el error:

`````
 ```` componentDidMount() {
    window.firebase.database().ref('messages/').on('value', snap => {
      const currentMessages = snap.val();
      if (currentMessages != null) {
        this.setState({
          messages: currentMessages
        });
      }
    });
  }````
`````

y luego me da el otro error en esta parte

`````
  ````handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newMessage = {
      id: this.state.messages.length,
      text: this.state.message
    };
    window.firebase.database().ref(`messages/${newMessage.id}`).set(newMessage);
    this.setState({message: ''});
}````
`````

al ejecutarlo me indica que:

> window.firebase.database is not a funtion

he importado *firebase* y aún así el error persiste podrían ayudarme?.

Comment: ¡Hola!, indícanos qué error estás obteniendo para poder ayudarte. Puede que el error lo veas en la consola donde ejecutas `npm start` o en la consola de tu navegador (F12)

Comment: donde seteas el valor de `firebase` a `window`? Sino lo haces (es lo que creo) tienes que importar `firebase` y llamarlo directamente.

Answer (score 0):

window no debería tener por defecto la propiedad `firebase`, por eso no lo encuentra.

para usar firebase en tu código, importa firebase y luego úsalo directamente.

Te pongo un ejemplo

// .../config/firebase.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/auth';

// Initialize Firebase wallacoin-front
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MSGSID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APPID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();

export const db = firebase.database();
export default firebase;
```

y en tu componente

```
import firebase from '../config/firebase';

firebase.database().ref('messages/').on('value', snap => {
  const currentMessages = snap.val();
  if (currentMessages != null) {
    this.setState({
      messages: currentMessages
    });
  }
});
```